# ggplot histogram with equal total bin counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

OK, so I have the following data:

```
> head(scores1,n=15)
       alt cat_name disorder  GS
8    V825I     Poly   0.0253  29
14  D2365N     Poly   0.2715  23
20    R43C      VLP   0.0123 180
34   P147L      VLP   0.1424  98
37   P186L      VLP   0.4441  98
40   G210V      VLP   0.2129 109
47   P248L      Mut   0.0092  98
52   R280C      VLP   0.0483 180
55   R288K      VLB   0.0414  26
56   E292V      Mut   0.0253 121
63   A414T      Mut   0.0062  58
68   A501E      VLB   0.4725 107
78   R589Q     Poly   0.2258  43
98   H778R     Poly   0.4409  29
111  D953N      VLB   0.1048  23
> tail(scores1,n=15)
         alt cat_name disorder  GS
54219  G191V     Poly   0.0120 109
54221 R1111L      Mut   0.2364 102
54227  I125R     Poly   0.1671  97
54228  K197R     Poly   0.5456  26
54229  N220K     Poly   0.6322  94
54232  E249A     Poly   0.6661 107
54234  C301R     Poly   0.5620 180
54235  D315E     Poly   0.5992  45
54239  A666V     Poly   0.2503  64
54246 G3631R     Poly   0.8623 125
54252  R300Q     Poly   0.3807  43
54253  T343M     Poly   0.1969  81
54268    A3V     Poly   0.9593  64
54270  G117V     Poly   0.4901 109
54271  R152H      VLB   0.3529  29
```

And I run the following code to bin the data based on `GS` and grouped by `cat_name`, and output a plot:

```
> ggplot (scores1, aes(GS, fill = cat_name)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 20)
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

**What I would like is a plot in which the total height of each of the bins is normalized to 1, so that I can see the relative ratios of each category in each bin, rather than the count.**

Thoughts?

Comment: It's helps to have a working example. Can you fix this so that you include code for creating your scores1 data (or a miniature version of it)?

Comment: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, y = ..density.., fill = clarity)) +
    geom_histogram()`?

Comment: Wouldn't the same thing be achieved by plotting your data as percentages (of the total for each group) rather than absolute values?

Comment: Just add `position = "fill"`, just like in `geom_bar`. Example: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, fill = clarity)) + geom_histogram(position = 'fill', color = 'grey90')`

Comment: `position = 'fill'` is the solution.  using `library(scales)` and `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) ` can help with nice axes

Comment: `position='fill'` is pretty much what I needed! Thanks!